# 2d array.variable - what does this do?

Tags: c++, arrays

I know the basics to arrays, 2d arrays, arraylist etc but i came accross this in a c++ project and I have no idea whas happening? Ive looked about and i haven't seen anything to explain the functionality.

```
var y = 2Darray[i][j].l;
var x = 2Darray[i][j].array[k];
```

Comment: That doesn't look much like C++. It it is, then we'd need to see the definitions of types `var` and `2DArray`. But note `2DArray` is not a valid identifier.

Comment: 2Darray[i][j] itself could be returning an object. You have to look at the datatype of 2Darray[i][j].

Comment: I understand the first bit which is the 2Darray[][] but i don't understand how the '.l' or '.array[k]' can be used like this, or what its doing.

Comment: This is not C++, go to JavaScript help.